# solaris10 stat command not found but works in perl

Tags: perl, stat, solaris-10

I was reading a [page](http://www.slashroot.in/which-is-the-fastest-method-to-delete-files-in-linux) about the performance of delete operation on thousands of files and it mentions the command below

```
perl -e 'for(<*>){((stat)[9]<(unlink))}'
```

Could anyone explain me why I have a 'command not found' while calling command 'stat' from the command-line while it's working through perl?

Comment: What do you mean by "calling 'stat' from the command-line"? The `stat` Perl function can only be called from within a Perl program (such as the one you posted).

Comment: [stat](http://p3rl.org/stat) is not [stat](http://linux.die.net/man/1/stat).

Comment: You can replicate `stat` on solaris with `truss`. Off the top of my head, something like `truss -t lstat64 -v lstat64 ls <path/file>`

Comment: I though the stat comman in perl in the one you see in the man page. Therefore on my bash prompt I just tried to call 'stat' but I haven't it installed.
So I want to know if perl is actually calling the system command 'stat' (I think it's the case) and if it's, is there a way for me to call it without using truss.
I saw some pages where the 'stat' command can be called from the shell prompt

Comment: No, perl is not calling the external program `stat`, nor the shell built-in `stat`. It calls the [C library function `stat`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat). So no, you can't call `stat` (the program) without installing it. Why can't you just use perl?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. It was just a question but of course I'll use perl as it's the fastest and working solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `stat` perl function is different from the `stat` program.

Likely you may be running this from an environment that doesn't have a `stat` program installed (Windows).